# I have cross browser front-end display issues on my contact form

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

I am attempting to build myself a portfolio and as part of a course I am taking I've prepared the front-end of a contact form.

I developed it keeping Google Chrome in mind and using a screen resolution of 1024x768px as the base, hence it looks good even on my 1920x1080px screen.

I've run into cross browser compatibility issues in the latest versions of IE and Firefox. The site looks and behaves fine on Google Chrome.

In IE:

- The comments box appears wider than the rest of the form elements
- The "Legend" title's font colour is black instead of white

In FireFox:

- The comments box and the "How did you find this site?" textbox are not aligned with the rest of the above form elements in terms of width size.

I am not particularly all that sure on how to get them to look more or less equal across all three browsers. To the best of my knowledge the CSS I used should be cross-browser supported.

Here's my code:

```css
        body {
          font-family: "Ludica Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
          background-color: #E0E1E3;
          margin: 0 auto;
          padding: 0;
        }
        h1 {
          color: #f5f5f5;
          font-size: 4em;
          padding: 0;
          margin: 0 auto;
        }
        .break {
          clear: both;
        }
        #header {
          margin: 0 auto;
          width: 100%;
          background-color: #FF4C65;
          text-align: center;
        }
        #wrapper {
          margin: 0 auto;
          padding: 0;
        }
        #loginContainer {
          position: relative;
          top: 100px;
          background-color: #21282E;
          color: #f5f5f5;
          margin: 0 auto;
          padding: 0;
          width: 400px;
          height: 390px;
        }
        fieldset {
          border: none;
          width: 90%;
          margin: 0 auto;
          padding: 0;
          text-align: center;
          height: 385px;
          color: #FF422C;
        }
        .spacer {
          display: inline-block;
          box-sizing: border-box;
          padding-left: 5px;
          height: 40px;
          line-height: normal;
          margin: 5px 7px 2px 7px;
          font-size: 0.81em;
        }
        textarea {
          margin-top: 5px;
          min-width: 325px;
          min-height: 150px;
          padding-left: 5px;
        }
        #survey {
          padding-top: 0;
          margin: 0;
          width: 325px;
          height: 40px;
          line-height: normal;
          padding-left: 5px;
        }
        #submitButton {
          margin-top: 10px;
          text-align: center;
          border: 0;
          width: 130px;
          height: 30px;
          background-color: #FF422C;
          cursor: pointer;
          color: white;
          transition: all 0.5s ease;
        }
        #submitButton:hover {
          background-color: grey;
        }
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="header">
    <h1>GET IN TOUCH</h1>
  </div>

  <!-- Clear the floats -->
  <div class="break"></div>

  <div id="loginContainer">
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Fill in your details here</legend>
      <form action="getintouch.php" type="get" id="getintouch">
        <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Full Name" class="spacer" required/>
        <input type="email" name="email" class="spacer" placeholder="Email" required/>
        <input type="tel" name="telephone" class="spacer" placeholder="Phone" required/>
        <input type="text" name="titleAndCompany" class="spacer" placeholder="Title and company" />
        <textarea name="comments" placeholder="What can I help you with?" required></textarea>
        <input type="text" name="survey" id="survey" placeholder="How did you find this site?" required/>
        <button type="submit" id="submitButton">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </fieldset>
  </div>

</div>
```

Here's a link to the jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/knadoor/bm2LbbL4/

Advice appreciated!! :-)

PS: For the experienced coders here, I'd love to get your opinion on the layout of my code (my background is not web development).

Thanks

**EDIT:**
Here's a link to my complete code snippet (I'm using the http://pastebin.com/gBJR1Nd3

The first picture is Google Chrome, second being Firefox and the third is IE.

[image: Google Chrome (runs fine)]

[image: On Firefox]

[image: Internet Explorer]

Comment: Would be great if you can provide screenshots for both problematic scenarios in IE and FF. You might not have enough reps, but just place the image url and I can insert the images when you get around to it.

Comment: Thans...I'll do that now

Comment: Use this as the first style: `* { box-sizing: border-box; margin: 0; padding: 0; }` and then work out your design from there.

Answer (score 2):

It is good to normalize or even reset your css code when you take care of making your website cross browser.

You can learn more on normalization here: http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/, it basically overrides defualt browser settings for CSS so that you can have more control over how things look.

Also, I can see you using `box-sizing` - make sure browsers you are aiming to are supporting this feature (adding `-webkit`, `-moz`, `-o` prefixes wouldn't hurt). Make sure your page has a correct doctype.

Other than that your code looks good and should not casu any troubles. It is nice seeing someone using proper `display` attributes.

Comment: Thanks but even with normalize.css (I've placed it prior to my CSS) the layout does not look even.

Comment: The part of your answer that I liked was the suggestion of using normalize.css which I've done. Though that did not solve my issue I later worked it out myself and the form looks great on high/low res and across all three browsers.

This stuff takes time to perfect across all browsers though!!